# How to fix text overflowing from <span>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this strange thing where the text in a div goes below it after I update from the original text in a script function. Example below ("Hello World" is default, "test" is the updated text)

[image]

[image]

**CSS**

```
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 800px;
  background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  color: #ac962a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #383838;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #383838;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
  <span id="botEvent">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

The `botEvent` id is what I am updating, and after the update the text goes below the original background box.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance and have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

do you have something else going on that's causing the problem? If you are using a p tag set margin and padding to 0

```js
document.getElementById('botEvent').textContent = 'TEST';
```

```css
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  color: #ac962a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #383838;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #383838;
}

p{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p id="botEvent">Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been playing around with it for a little bit, and I'm getting the same result of the text going below the background when I just use the <p> tag instead of <span>

Example:
```<div id="footer">
  <p id="botEvent">Hello World</p>
</div>```

Comment: Hmm, something else must be the problem then. Thanks for your help.